# Get hostname from MAC address on Windows

Tags: windows, networking

How can I [Get Hostname from IP address/MAC address](https://superuser.com/questions/219173/get-hostname-from-ip-address-mac-address) on Windows? (Win7, if it's version dependent)

I know that `arp -a` will give me a table of IP and MAC. Is there something similar for Hostname and MAC/IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start with a MAC address, you first need to get the IP address.  This means that you need access to a device that has the IP address associated with the MAC.  As per the question, `arp -a` will list the MAC addresses and corresponding IP addresses.  In order to populate that list, the machine will have had to at some point issued an `arp` request, saying "who has IP x.x.x.x" - the owner will reply and upon receipt, the arp table will be populated.

In order for this to work, both devices must be on the same layer 2 network - the same switch/vlan.  You can trigger arp requests manually by pinging every IP on the network, or using a utility like `nmap` to do them all in one go.

Once you have the IP address, you are relying on a name resolution service to do a reverse lookup and return a hostname that is associated with an IP.

In DNS this is achieved through PTR records.  For each IP address, there is a PTR record in which is stored the associated hostname.  *However, there is no obligation to store PTR records so they may not be present, in which case the lookup will fail*.

They look like this:

```
13.12.11.10.in-addr.arpa. 900   IN      PTR     hostname.domain.com.
```

The IP address in the PTR record is reversed.  So to get the hostname of 10.11.12.13, we say to DNS "Give me the PTR record for 13.12.11.10.in-addr.arpa."

It returns the above record.  You can achieve this in by doing

`nslookup 10.11.12.13`

When `nslookup` is given an IP address, it will try to do a PTR lookup.

As per the other reply, if the IP belongs to a Windows machine, you can also do `nbtstat -A 10.31.46.59` (note the uppercase -A)

Comment: ok, to boil this down: do `arp -a ` to show table of MAC to IP addresses, then follow with `nslookup ...` (or `nbstat -A ` on Windows) on each IP in order to get the hostname. That about capture it?

Comment: @mattwilkie Yes - though on linux, by default `arp -a` will do a reverse lookup by default (that you switch off with `-n`) and so get there in one step if possible

Answer (score 0):

nbtstat -A 192.168.1.100

192.168.1.100 is the target address

Answer (score 0):

`Ping -a <ip address>`

This will parse your reverse lookup zone in DNS.

If you don't have a reverse lookup zone it will lookup in your local name cache.

If you don't have an entry it will do a broadcast on your LAN (within the subnet you are in) to query for it.

This only for IP > hostname resolution.  No MACs.

Comment: Could you please add a sample output?